# how to make a div clickable in order to open a link?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make this div clickable to redirect to another page ?

```
<div aria-describedby="slick-slide12" aria-hidden="true" class="slide all-slider-category-gallery slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" role="option" style="background-image: url(); width: 280px;" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to your `div`:

```
<div onclick="window.location = 'http://www.yoururl.com'">
```

Change the URL to your desired link.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://google.com/';" style="cursor: pointer;"</div>
```

Use `a` tag to making the div clickable:

```css
#my-div {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
a.fill-div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
It is possible to make a link fill the entire div which gives the appearance of making the div clickable.
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="fill-div"></a>
</div>
```